# What is the update app solutions for apps that developed by react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Please let me know; how can I auto update my react-native application that installed on my customer device? How can I send Updates? is it with push notification and send a link for get update and install new version of my app or its not good?
please help me to improve my app features.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one question that you must ask yourself: `are my updates optional?`

if your updates are just improving some user experience and some changes in UI which you don't care if someone is still using an out-dated version of your app, this means your updates are optional.
but if you have some logic or other things that you must make sure each user is using the latest version of your app, it means your updates are no longer optional.

you may ask: `why answer to question above matters`?

the point is if your updates are a must and not optional, you must implement a process to block user further progress in app startup unless user goes and updates the application. let me provide an example thinking you are not using any `store` to publish your app and you just have an `apk`. imagine there is an API (in `back-end`) providing the current version of application e.g `v1.0`. in application you stored its version, in application startup you compare these two values. if they were not equal you just open a `Modal` showing a message: `Your app is not up to date, in order to update your app click on link below` then you provide a link to somewhere to download & update the application.
it can be a link to your `apk` directly or it can open the page of your app in an `store`.

Now lets answer: `How to publish my app updates?`.

if you publish your application in an `store` like `Appstore - Playstore` you just update your application there and `stores` handle the rest. user can come in `store` and update the application. i assume we all do it periodically for apps on our phone. remember making your user have to come here to update or letting it be optional is your choice as said above.

or you can use `Code-Push`.

> CodePush is a cloud service that enables Cordova and React Native
> developers to deploy mobile app updates directly to their users'
> devices

its github link: https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push

as an experience if you can put it correctly in your application, updating will be so pleasant although it has some limitations(e.g it can only publish codes in js part and not native codes)

Comment: thanx a lot for your complete and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Microsoft code push](https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push) for automatic updates without actually updating the app through PlayStore or AppStore

Here is a great [article](https://medium.com/myntra-engineering/updating-apps-on-the-fly-aab40c26fac2) on how Microsoft code push works in real app Like Myntra.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo you can use Over-the-Air Updates

More details  https://docs.expo.io/bare/updating-your-app/

Comment: unfortunately I didn't use Expo. but thank you for your time and answer.